# How to save large data in the database without the maximum execution time error in php

Tags: php, arrays, database, codeigniter, csv

I have this huge problem and I don't know where to begin.. I need to save a large data like 100,000 records in the database and i'm using a for loop in there to save the data one by one.. but since it's too large it consumes a lot of time therefore triggering the PHP Fatal Error of maximum execution time of 30 seconds.

The data I'm inserting comes from a CSV File.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: It is significantly faster if you insert it using one query instead of 100,000 individual queries.

Comment: can you help me out? how am i gonna do that? something like insert_batch in codeigniter not working for me

Comment: I don't know codeigniter, but what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: can you please help me? how to use a single query to insert that large data?

Comment: Not if you don't answer my questions.

Comment: wow.. :-) ok i tried this insert_batch function of codeigniter but it returns an error in the next array of the batch.. I don't know why so what i did is i inserted the data one by one using the for loop..

Comment: http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/usage/ -maybe this could help...